# T-SQL: BACKUP CERTIFICATE - Using variables with the T-SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ddl

I have a set of t-sql statements like the following:

```
DECLARE @somefilepath as nvarchar = 'c:\somedir\somefile.ext';
DECLARE @anotherfilepath as nvarchar = 'c:\somedir\somefile2.ext';
DECLARE @somepassword as nvarchar = 'password';
BACKUP CERTIFICATE MyCertificate TO FILE = @somefilepath
WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = @anotherfilepath,
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = @somepassword);
```

when I execute 'parse' to test the statements, I get: incorrect syntax near '@somefilepath'.It looks like variables can not be used in this type of statement. Can someone please help me to understand if this is true?

Is there anyway to get this backup to work with variables?

I have a larger script and I want users to be able to easily change the paths and passwords in one location rather than having to search the file for locations requiring a manual change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE
   @somefilepath as nvarchar(255) = 'c:\somedir\somefile.ext',
   @anotherfilepath as nvarchar(255) = 'c:\somedir\somefile2.ext',
   @somepassword as nvarchar(100) = 'password',
   @SQL as nvarchar(max);

SET @SQL = 'BACKUP CERTIFICATE MyCertificate TO FILE = ' + QuoteName(@somefilepath, '''') + '
WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = ' + QuoteName(@anotherfilepath, '''') + ',
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ' + QuoteName(@somepassword, '''') + ');';
EXEC (@SQL);
```

Also, **always, always** specify a length for your `char` data types. It will bite you badly some day if you don't get in this habit. Here are reasons why:

- In stored procedures, the default length for an `n/var/char` parameter without a length defined is 1 character.
- In other contexts, the default length for an `n/var/char` parameter is 30 characters, which *may* be fine for the `varchar` versions but almost definitely wrong for `char`. If the value is used to create a table using SELECT INTO, it will be a mysterious length instead of an explicitly chosen one.
- Not explicitly defining your lengths forces the next developer who visits your code to know the exact rules for `varchar` lengths and is likely to trick him into error since it is implicit instead of explicit. Let's say the length of a column needs to change, forcing parameter length changes, too, but since the parameter doesn't have a length it gets skipped over.
- If you really did want 1 character or 30 characters, it's better to specify it so that the next developer visiting the code doesn't see the lack of length as an error and waste time trying to figure out what it is supposed to be or whether that was a mistake.
- It will help your reputation by sparing you from being secretly laughed at as an ignorant beginner by experts.

Comment: You can use `QUOTENAME(@somefilepath, '''')`

Comment: Ah yes, thanks @Remus, I forgot you could supply a character to `quotename`.

Comment: @ErikE Thank you! This worked perfectly. I'll keep in mind your point about specifying lengths for char data types. What is the reason for this suggestion? Understanding the why will help me to remember to do so.